# Semantics of Linux O_PATH file descriptors?

Tags: c, linux, posix

Linux 2.6.39 introduced `O_PATH` open mode, which (roughly speaking) doesn't really open the file at all (i.e. doesn't create an open file description), but just gives a file descriptor that's a handle to the unopened target. Its main use is as an argument to the `*at` functions (`openat`, etc.), and it seems to be suitable as an implementation of the POSIX 2008 `O_SEARCH` functionality which Linux was previously missing. However, I've been unable to find any good documentation on the exact semantics of `O_PATH`. A couple specific questions I have are:

1. What operations are possible on Linux `O_PATH` file descriptors? (Only `*at` functions?)
2. Is `O_PATH` ever useful with non-directories?
3. How is the file descriptor bound to the underlying filesystem object, and what happens if it's moved, deleted, etc.? Does an `O_PATH` file descriptor count as a reference that prevents the object from being freed when the last link is unlinked? Etc.

Comment: I had hoped to use an O_PATH file descriptor for capabilities managed via `cap_get_fd` and `cap_set_fd`. But this didn't work, I got a bad file descriptor error. Too bad.

Comment: @MvG: Have you tried using `cap_get_file` and `cap_set_file` on the `/proc/self/fd/` entries for the `O_PATH` file descriptors you opened? This seems to be a workaround for **all** of the kernel's failure to let you directly use `O_PATH` file descriptors, and the `proc` entry is permanently pegged to the inode (it's not really a symlink even though it shows up as one in the directory listing) so this method is race-free just like using the fd directly would be.

Comment: @R: Since in my actual application, I have read permission, I simply opened the file for reading. But thanks for the info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

File descriptors obtained using `open(directory, O_PATH | O_DIRECTORY)` are not only useful for `...at()` functions, but for `fchdir()` (since kernel version 3.2.23, I believe).

There is also a recent [patch](http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=134504937124533) for a new syscall, [`fbind()`](http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=134504828424171), that would allow very long Unix domain socket names. The socket file is first created using `mknod(path, mode | S_IFSOCK, (dev_t)0)`, then opened using `open(file, O_PATH)`. The file descriptor thus obtained, and a Unix domain socket descriptor, is passed to `fbind()`, to bind the socket to the pathname. Whether this will be included in the Linux kernel is yet to be seen -- although even if it is, it will be years before one can rely on it being universally available. (As a workaround for too-long Unix domain socket names it would be viable sooner, though.)

I'd say `O_PATH` is only useful for directories for now; file uses may be found in the future. Other than the possibility of a future `fbind()`, or similar future syscalls, I don't know of any use of file descriptors for files opened using `O_PATH`. Even `fstatvfs()` won't work, on a 3.5.0 kernel at least.

In Linux, inodes (file contents and metadata) are freed only when the last open file descriptor is closed. When removing (unlinking) a file, you only remove the file name associated with the inode. So, there are *two* separate filesystem objects associated with a file descriptor: the name used to open the object, and the underlying inode referred to. The name is only used for path resolution, i.e. when `open()` (or equivalent) is called. All data and metadata is in the inode.

File descriptors obtained using `O_PATH` behave (at least on kernel 3.5.0) just like normal file descriptors wrt. moving and renaming the name or name components used to open the descriptor. (The descriptor stays valid, as it refers to the inode, and the file name object was used only during path resolution. Holding the descriptor open will keep the inode resources allocated, even if the descriptor was opened `O_PATH`.)

Comment: One use you missed for files is that `O_PATH` works to provide `O_EXEC`, i.e. `fd=open("my_prog", O_PATH); snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "/proc/self/fd/%d", fd); execl(fd, "my_prog", (char *)0);` works to execute `my_prog` even if you don't have read permissions to the file.

Comment: @R.. Right; good catch. I also don't remember checking if you can obtain a file lease on such descriptors. If you can, it would be yet another use. (You have a typo in your snippet: should be `execl(buf, "my_prog", (char *)0);`, I think.)